# Azure Active Directory tenant for a stand-alone Azure Installation with Domain Services

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, remote-desktop, azure-vpn

we have an Infrastructure for one customer in Azure which require many configurations like MFA with VPN and Remote Desktop (this one is the reason why I'm confused with Azure AD).

The installation should be only in Azure, that's mean there is no local AD which could be synced to it.

I've created an seperated Azure Directory for them and configured an AD DS inside it so I can join the Azure VMs to it.

My problem here is I was asked to configure MFA for remote desktop users along with the VPN connection. The requirement the MFA that I should install an local NPS with MFA Extenstion and the local AD users should be synced with Azure AD. Which in my case it's not possible to do it since there is no local Network for this customer.
This problem as I understood is because that we don't have permissions to administrate Azure AD DS Active Directory and by this we can't register the NPS with MFA Extension with it. here are some Links related to this topic:

1. [Request to Support NPS/RADIUS for Azure AD Domain Services](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/34781713-support-nps-radius-for-azure-ad-domain-services)
2. [Integrate Remote Desktop Gateway with Azure MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-nps-extension-rdg)
3. [Integrate VPN with Azure MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-nps-extension-vpn)

My question here is:
1) the seperated Azure AD for this tenant is a good Idea? Is it not better to just create an Azure AD Domain Services inside our Company Azure AD and sync the required groups to it? what is the best practice for this situation?

2) In order to use the Azure MFA here, what should I do? is there any other option in Azure to implement such a scenario?

I will be glad for any help or explaination.